# Keep getting errors on my Pointer code in c++ for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, pointers

So I am experimenting with pointers as I am quite new to C++ programming  the error p1 was not declared in this scope keeps coming up I have no clue what's wrong I have searched the deepest corners of the internet to no avail.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    int num1 = 8;
    *p1 = &num1;

    cout << "VALUE:" <<  *p1 <<endl;
    cout << "adress" << &num1 <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious that the error is that `p1` is not declared. So the question is -- do you think `p1` is declared? If so, where? Do you think `p1` doesn't need to be declared? If so, why?

Answer (score 6):

You have not mentioned the type of `*p1 = &num1;` - it should be:

```
int num1 = 8;
int *p1 = &num1;
```